# GMail API How To Get Mail's Unique URL?

Tags: gmail-api

GMail API is returning a list of messages and full message using these two calls

service.Users.Messages.list  (for getting message IDs)
service.Users.Messages.get (for getting full message by ID)

Wondering if there is a way to get the unique URL of each message? (just like Google Drive API provides a unique url of each document).

Comment: Gmail messages are not hosted in the same way like files with Drive API. Files can be accessed through URL but messages/emails cannot be accessed through URL directly. So, unique URL is not generated for each message..

Comment: @SGC I am sure emails can be accessed through URL directly. it's just that google does not / has not exposed an API to get the URL directly.

Just copy and paste any URL when viewing a mail using the web client on gmail to verify it. 

the url still points to the mail, even when we delete the mail/move it around. 

it'd be in the following format:

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?pli=1#inbox/14d41c2ba0852c78

as for how to get the '14d41c2ba0852c78' portion (ie OP's original question), it still feels like a mystery.